# How to create a function that checks if values in 2 columns of a PySpark dataframe matches values in the same 2 columns of another dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

How would you create a function that checks if values in two PySpark columns of a dataframe matches values in the same two columns of another Pysark dataframe? I want to make a new column that shows validation if those values in the two columns exists in the other dataframe. The dataframes don't have identical columns, except for the two columns to join on. I'm new to PySpark. The code below shows a function that identifies validations when matching on one column:

```
def isValue_inTable(df1, df2, column_name, 
df2_nonCorresponding_column):
   df3 = (df1.join(df2, on=column_name, how='left')     
     .withColumn('Value_inTable', 
     F.when(df2[df2_nonCorresponding_column].isNull(), 
     False).otherwise(True)))
df3.select(column_name, 'Value_inTable').show()
```

The function above can show whether a value in one column of a PySpark df is existant in another df in the same column. I want to modify this code to allow the function to match values in two columns in df1 to two columns in df2 and let the user know if the values in the two columns in df1 exist in the two columns in df2. For example:

| firstname | lastname | gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | Smith | M |
| Anna | Rose | F |
| Robert | Williams | M |

| firstname | lastname | gender | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gerogie | Smith | M | 3000 |
| Anna | Rose | F | 4100 |
| Robert | Williams | M | 6200 |

| firstname | lastname | values_do_notExist_inOtherTable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | Smith | true |
| Anna | Rose | false |
| Robert | Williams | false |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `left join` on both `firstname` and `lastname` and then construct `values_do_notExist_inOtherTable` based on `null` condition.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1_data = [("Sam", "Smith", "M", ), ("Anna", "Rose", "F", ), ("Robert", "Williams", "M", ), ]
df2_data = [("Gerogie", "Smith", "M", 3000, ), ("Anna", "Rose", "F", 4100, ), ("Robert", "Williams", "M", 6200, )]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df1_data, ("firstname", "lastname", "gender", ))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df2_data, ("firstname", "lastname", "gender", "salary", ))


def isValue_inTable(df1, df2, join_columns):
    return (df1.join(df2, on=join_columns, how="left")
    .withColumn("values_do_notExist_inOtherTable", F.when(df2[join_columns[0]].isNull() | 
                                                          df2[join_columns[1]].isNull(), True).otherwise(False))
    .select(df1["firstname"], df1["lastname"], df1["gender"], "values_do_notExist_inOtherTable"))

isValue_inTable(df1, df2, ["firstname", "lastname"]).show()
```

### Output

```
|firstname|lastname|gender|values_do_notExist_inOtherTable|
+---------+--------+------+-------------------------------+
|     Anna|    Rose|     F|                          false|
|   Robert|Williams|     M|                          false|
|      Sam|   Smith|     M|                           true|
+---------+--------+------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: how would it be done in a function format though? I try putting it in function format and the error states that the columns are ambiguous.

Comment: The logic being inside or outside function is immaterial, I can update the example to be of a function. `df2_nonCorresponding_column` is removed from the function since it's not needed and the join columns can be used to find missing records. If this does not help you, then consider updating the question with the error you are observing.